# SQL Server - Denormalizing join tables to improve performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, denormalization

Currently I've got a huge User table, couple of million rows I think, and that user table is linked to a UserType table through a UserTypeJoin table. Searching and filtering is taking a really long time because of all the joins to the UserType table.

I've looked into using an Indexed View, that looked great to start with but when I tried to create the clustered index I was told that clustered indexes can't be applied to views with left joins. And not all Users have a UserType, so I need to do a left join.

So now I'm thinking that denormalization is my best approach.

My current table structure looks something like this:

```
USER
UserId
UserName
Sex
Description

USER TYPE JOIN
UserId
UserTypeId

USER TYPE
UserTypeId
Name
```

And I'm thinking of changing the structure to this:

```
USER
UserId
UserName
IsUserTypeX bit
IsUserTypeY bit
IsUserTypeZ bit
etc...
```

A User can have between 0 and 11 UserTypes.

A typical query I'd be running against my data would be to search for users using their name, sex, description, or user types, or a combination of these attributes.

These tables are used mainly for searching and not so much for writing to, and all the research I've been doing lately tells me that read intensive tables should be denormalized.

Is this my best option in this situation?

Or is there a way of creating the Indexed View without using a left join but still return all rows? That would definitely be the easier approach as I wouldn't have to change large amounts of code.

Comment: Have you considered of using stored procedure?

Comment: No, but how's that going to help me in this situation? I'm still going to have the table joins slowing it down.

Comment: Why would you want to return the users who had no usertype?

Comment: You will but Stored procedures are being optimised by SQL server and their execution plans are being stored. Plus in execution plan analysis you can see how you could optimise your indexes an other stuff. Table structure change IMHO is last resort.

Comment: How long is it taking to do a left join on the entire set?  How long do you expect it to take?  Have you tried doing an inner join just for timing comparison purposes? Do you know what plan is used to execute your query?

Comment: This is a reasonable candidate for a denormaised table - 1 to 1 relationship and mostly reads. I'd go for it.

Comment: persisting a denormalized table might be an option but i would first check the queries which are slow and see if there is any possibility for optimization (additional indices and the like)

Comment: I've looked at execution plans, played around a lot with indexes and that's improved the performance a lot. 

I've tested the speed of getting just the Users vs Users with UserTypes and the difference is huge.

Comment: How many user types are there?

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' 11

Comment: I would first suggest to merge USE TYPE and USER TYPE JOIN tables - storing UserTypeName directly in join table instead of UserTypeId. This way you have to join two, not three tables. Well, generally such N-N relations (over three tables) should not cause major performance hits - but of course we don't know, what kind of queries you need to perform.

Comment: I wonder if the structure you proposed will give you a performance benefit. Usually it does not make sense to create an index on a bit column so i don't think it will speed up queries which filter for UserType.

Comment: Have you considered duplicating username into the USER TYPE JOIN table and basically keeping everything else as well? Because you have no min/max of user types, it could quickly be a problem and too much data to denormalize the types into the USER table. I'd also like to see an execution plan because perhaps indexed views or filtered indexes or similar could help you as well

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen sorry I meant to write there's no limit to the amount of user types, up to 11

Comment: @Arvo I've updated the question with the type of queries I'll be running on this data

Answer (score 2):

One thing you may wish to do, in this case, is to add one more UserType,  let's call it "Untyped".  Make this the default type when inserting new users.  Now you can use an inner join and not lose any rows.  It's klunkier data management, but the trade off may be worth it in your case.

Are you retrieving all the rows and then filtering?  There are a lot of situations where it's better to do the filtering first, and then the join.  The query optimizer usually uses this strategy if you put the filter criteria in the same query as the join.